# Node.js async function with while loop and array push

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, while-loop, async-await

I hope someone can help me with this. This is part of my Controller having an async function to get some reservations. The await Calls to my Overview-Model resolve in promises. The problem is the while-loop I guess. It should look for reservations for all the hours between the opening and closure but when I console.log it at the end, I just get the last line and same hour x times.

```
while (time_ < clubClosure) {
            const res_ = []
            for (const court of courts) {
                const result = await Overview.getReservation(court.court_id, time_)

                const reservation = new Reservation('free', null)
                if (!result.kind) {

                    if (result.tournament_name) {
                        const tournament = new Tournament(result.tournament_name)
                        reservation.tournament = tournament
                        reservation.type = 'tournament'
                    } else if (result.opponent) {
                        const matchday = new Matchday(result.team_name, result.opponent)
                        reservation.matchday = matchday
                        reservation.type = 'matchday'
                    } else {
                        const members_ = await Overview.getMembers(result.reservation_id)
                        const members = []
                        reservation.type = 'regular'
                        for (const member_ of members_) {
                            const member = new Member(member_.first_name, member_.last_name, member_.trainer, member_.reserver)

                            if (member.trainer == 1) {
                                reservation.type = 'training'
                            }
                            members.push(member)
                        }
                        reservation.members = members

                    }
                }
                res_.push(reservation)
            }
            const time = new Time(time_)
            time.reservation = res_

            reservations.push(time)
            time_.setHours(time_.getHours() + 1) // sets time to next hour
        }
        console.log(reservations) // prints last line x times
        res.status(200).json({
            courts,
            reservations
        })
```

Output (same hour x times):

```
[
  Time {
    start: 2021-06-06T22:00:00.000Z,
    reservation: [ [Reservation], [Reservation], [Reservation], [Reservation] ]
  },
  Time {
    start: 2021-06-06T22:00:00.000Z,
    reservation: [ [Reservation], [Reservation], [Reservation], [Reservation] ]
  },
  Time {
    start: 2021-06-06T22:00:00.000Z,
    reservation: [ [Reservation], [Reservation], [Reservation], [Reservation] ]
  },
  Time {
    start: 2021-06-06T22:00:00.000Z,
    reservation: [ [Reservation], [Reservation], [Reservation], [Reservation] ]
  }
]
```

I have tried it with a predefined set of times and ran them in a for-of-loop instead of the while-loop and that worked correctly so it must be the while-loop I guess.

```
const time1 = clubOpening
let time2 = new Date(time1)
time2.setHours(time2.getHours() + 1)
let time3 = new Date(time2)
time3.setHours(time3.getHours() + 1)

const times = [time1, time2, time3]

for (const time_ of times) { // with for-of loops for predefined times-array it works
     // code as above
}
```